# how to call a function when parameter is not needed? what is the correct way

Tags: javascript

this should be fairly simple, but want to make sure...

```
function load_img(src, alt, el, other_src) {

// check if other_src exists, not null, defined, not empty, etc...

}

//call the function
load_img(src, alt, '#zoom-cover');
```

Is that the ok way to call the function when a parameter is not needed..
Should i write:

```
load_img(src, alt, '#zoom-cover', null);
```

or

```
load_img(src, alt, '#zoom-cover', '');
```

is there something similar like php

```
load_img(src, alt, '#zoom-cover', other_src='default value');
```

and... how do i check, in the function, that other_src exists, is defined, has a valid value, is not null or empty string?

Answer (score 0):

You can just omit the last argument if it is not needed. With the example you've given, that'd be:

```
load_img(src, alt, '#zoom-cover');
```

About your second question, you could simply do something like:

```
if(typeof other_src === 'undefined') {
    ...
}
```

JavaScript does not have *named arguments* ("like php"). Instead, though, you could pass in an object, like:

```
load_img(src, alt, '#zoom-cover', {other_src: 'something'});
```

This is a technique commonly used by *jQuery Plugins*.

Answer (score 0):

This is fine

```
load_img(src, alt, '#zoom-cover');
```

If you want a default value to represent other_src when the parameter is not passed or null then do this:

```
function load_img(src, alt, el, other_src) {
  if (!other_src) {
    other_src = "mydefaultvalue"
  }
}
```

or something like this if you want the default value to represent other_src when the parameter is just not passed.

```
function load_img(src, alt, el, other_src) {
  if (typeof(other_src) === "undefined") {
    other_src = "mydefaultvalue"
  }
}
```

Comment: `undefined !== 'undefined'` Undefined is not a string.

Comment: Just to clear that up: if you test the value of a variable for undefined it's: `if(other_src!==undefined)`. Using it like a string above only works because `typeof` always returns a string. I used to get that wrong in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Just omit the extra parameters.

If you want to supply a default, use

```
other_src = other_src || 'default value';
```

in the top of your function, although this isn't appropriate if the original value could legitimately be "falsey", in which case:

```
if (typeof other_src === 'undefined') {
    other_src = 'default value';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In JS, if you don't pass a parameter, the local variable gets an 'undefined' type.
so you can call the function without all the parameters.

```
load_img(src, alt, '#zoom-cover');
```